# log in to microsoft teams with a secret

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

with below script I can authenticate on AzureAd with a secret but not on teams.
Can you please point me in the right direction how to do this for MicrosoftTeams ?

```
import-module Az
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
$azureAplicationId ="xxxx"
$azureTenantId= "yyyyy"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken

Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCred
```

output:

WARNING: The provided service principal secret will be included in the 'AzureRmContext.json' file found in the user profile ( C:\Users\jdeclerc.Azure ). Please ensure th
at this directory has appropriate protections.

Account SubscriptionName TenantId Environment

xxxxx yyyyyy AzureCloud

Account : xxxxx
Environment : AzureCloud
Tenant : yyyyy
TenantId : yyyyy
TenantDomain : yyyyy

Connect-MicrosoftTeams : One or more errors occurred.: unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
At line:13 char:1

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCred

- CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], AadAuthenticationFailedException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-MicrosoftTeams,Microsoft.Open.Teams.CommonLibrary.ConnectMicrosoftTeams

Connect-MicrosoftTeams : One or more errors occurred.
At line:13 char:1

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCred

- CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], AggregateException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-MicrosoftTeams,Microsoft.Open.Teams.CommonLibrary.ConnectMicrosoftTeams

Connect-MicrosoftTeams : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
At line:13 char:1

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCred

- CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], AdalException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-MicrosoftTeams,Microsoft.Open.Teams.CommonLibrary.ConnectMicrosoftTeams

Connect-MicrosoftTeams : One or more errors occurred.: unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
At line:13 char:1

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $psCred

- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-MicrosoftTeams], AadAuthenticationFailedException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Teams.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Open.Teams.CommonLibrary.ConnectMicrosoftTeams

Comment: Hi @johan de clercq, 
For this error : Connect-MicrosoftTeams : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type At line:13 char:1
You need to pass credentials - username and password instead of secret.

Comment: Could you please try this command -                                                             
 Connect-MicrosoftTeams
       [-TenantId ]
       -AadAccessToken 
       [-MsAccessToken ]
       [-ConfigAccessToken ]
       -AccountId 
       [-LogLevel ]
       [-LogFilePath ]
       [-WhatIf]
       [-Confirm]
       []

Comment: de clercq, Could you please let us know the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

For this error : Connect-MicrosoftTeams : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type At line:13 char:1 You need to pass credentials - username and password instead of secret.
Could you please try this command - Connect-MicrosoftTeams [-TenantId ] -AadAccessToken [-MsAccessToken ] [-ConfigAccessToken ] -AccountId [-LogLevel ] [-LogFilePath ] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [] –